# Distributed Leaderboard for p2p games

Tags: leaderboards

I've heard about this term distributed leaderboard for p2p games and I've searched it online but couldn't find much of a thing about it.I was curious what does it really mean and didn't really knew where to ask.Do you guys know what does it mean to have a distributed leaderboard? it's something like a global leaderboard but for p2p players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you can do distributed monetary balances in cryptocurrencies via public and private keys, you could build a distributed leaderboard by hashing the result (a transaction of sorts between players) and passing it around. Everyone who connects to someone will have a validated list of players beaten and beat by that player, and any ranking system based on that information can be calculated on the fly.

[I suggest reading up about Bitcoin transactions here](https://www.coindesk.com/information/how-do-bitcoin-transactions-work/) to get you started.